# How can I code a color change of pasted text

Tags: html, excel, vba, text, format

I have several lines of text where I insert data, including names, into cells and then email the excel workbook to a list of people. I have coded the email to display certain info into the body of the email so the user can see that data before opening the file.  Currently some of the text, such as titles, etc, are formatted to do certain thing. (In the example below, "TEXT" is pasted as bold and underlined.) I would like to also change the color to red, but adding `<span style="color: #ff0000;">` doesn't work: It gives a "Compile Error: Expected end of statement" error. Any ideas on how to properly code the color change?

`"<p><b><u>TEXT:</u></b>" & " " & Range("A6")`

Also, I am trying to change the formatting of the copied cell in the body of the email when VBA puts it into the email. (If the text in Range("A6") is "Smith," for example, I want "Smith" to show as Bold but not underlined.)

Here is what I am trying to code, but can't get it to work:

`"<p><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong><u>Sergeant:</u></strong></span></p>" & " " & "<b>Range("A6")</b>"`

Any help will more than greatly appreciated by this rookie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double up on your quotes, and do not include your `Range` reference within the quotes.

Also, make sure you are using `.HTMLBody` and not `.Body`

It should look like this:

```
"<p><span style=""color: #ff0000;""><strong><u>Sergeant:</u></strong></span></p><b>" & Range("A6") & "</b>"
```

and technically, you dont even need the quotes for such a simple style:

```
"<p><span style=color:#ff0000><strong><u>Sergeant:</u></strong></span></p><b>" & Range("A6") & "</b>"
```

and since `<span>` is just an empty inline container tag, you can use the `<p>` as your container in this example:

```
"<p style=color:#ff0000><strong><u>Sergeant:</u></strong></p><b>" & Range("A6") & "</b>"
```

You could even use all styles instead of some of those old HTML tags:

```
"<div style=color:#ff0000; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;>Sergeant:</div><b>" & Range("A6") & "</b>"
```

They should all do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much! This got me where I needed to be!